# THREE.MTLLoader does not load texture image

Tags: javascript, three.js

i create a three js program that load mtl and obj and show on scene
when run program show no texture and show black object.

i use mtl loader and obj loader and add files in root folder of host
this code work on three js site fine and i copy this code in my program but dont work for me.

i also use light ambien light and point light.

its link my model : [my program](https://onlinedota.com)

here my code:

```
        import * as THREE from './three.module.js';
        import { DDSLoader } from './jsm/loaders/DDSLoader.js';
        import { MTLLoader } from './jsm/loaders/MTLLoader.js';
        import { OBJLoader } from './jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js';

        var container;

        var camera, scene, renderer;

        var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;


        init();
        animate();


        function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
            camera.position.z = 250;

            // scene

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc, 0.4 );
            scene.add( ambientLight );

            var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
            camera.add( pointLight );
            scene.add( camera );

            // model

            var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {

                if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {

                    var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                    console.log( Math.round( percentComplete, 2 ) + '% downloaded' );

                }

            };

            var onError = function () { };

            var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
            manager.addHandler( /\.dds$/i, new DDSLoader() );

            // comment in the following line and import TGALoader if your asset uses TGA textures
            // manager.addHandler( /\.tga$/i, new TGALoader() );

            new MTLLoader( manager )
                .setPath( '/' )
                .load( 'char4.mtl', function ( materials ) {
                                            console.log(materials);
                    materials.preload();

                    new OBJLoader( manager )
                        .setMaterials( materials )
                        .setPath( '/' )
                        .load( 'char4.obj', function ( object ) {
                                                            object.scale.set(20,20,20);
                            scene.add( object );

                        }, onProgress, onError );

                } );

            //

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

            mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) / 2;
            mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) / 2;

        }

        //

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();

        }

        function render() {

            camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
            camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;

            camera.lookAt( scene.position );

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Your MLT file contains a `Kd` entry which represents the diffuse color and a `map_Kd` entry which represents a diffuse color texture. E.g.

```
Kd 0.00 0.00 0.00
map_Kd char4.png
```

So the diffuse color is black. The (unofficial) [MTL spec](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/mtl/) says: *material diffuse is multiplied by the texture value*. And that means all final color values are black in your case.

You can easily fix the issue my changing all `Kd` values to `1.00 1.00 1.00`.